# is there any editable combobox in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to add editable combo box in GWT , so please tell me the solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Advanced GWT Components](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/text-and-button.html), specifically

```
org.gwt.advanced.client.ui.widget.ComboBox
```

You can see them in action at the demo page [here](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/demo/index.html), just select the `Text & Button Widgets` tab and have  look at the source code behind it.